# How do i solve this?

Tags: geometry

Which of the following would result from multiplying each side of the polygon by a ratio of $\frac{1}{2}$?
[image: triangle]

The final area is $24\text{ km}^2$

The final perimeter is $12\text{ km}$

The final area is $12\text{ km}^2$

The final perimeter is $24\text{ km}$

I'm confused is it 12^2 that i got from the area 1/2*8*6 or 12 km from the perimeter 6+8+10=24*1/2?

Answer (score 1):

Well just try to compute the following and compare with what you were given: $$\dfrac12\times\text{area}=\dfrac12\times\left(\dfrac12\times \text{base}\times \text{height}\right)\quad\color{grey}{\text{and}}\quad \dfrac12\times\text{perimeter}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Area of triangle is just $\frac{1}{2}bh$ where $b$ is the length of the base and $h$ is the height. Perimeter of triangle is just the sum of all the side lengths.